# configure haproxy to detect failed webservers

Tags: haproxy

I have two webservers:

- WEB A: 192.168.0.3
- WEB B: 192.168.0.4

and am using haproxy to load balance between them.

How do I configure haproxy to detect when WEB A or WEB B dies and stop forwarding connections there?

Answer (score 3):

You want to ask haproxy to use HTTP status checks to detect failed servers.

Search the [configuration guide](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Supermathie/haproxy/master/doc/configuration.txt) for `http-check` and `httpchk`.

You'll end up with something like:

```
backend brazzers
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option httpchk GET /status HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ api.brazzers.com
        server  bz_00 10.0.0.1:8000 check
        server  bz_01 10.0.0.2:8000 check
```